# I have a working combination console application but I want to make some changes and I need some assistance

Tags: c#, math

hello I couldn't explain it in the title but what I want to do is make the r permanently "2" and I want it not show it to me when I open the application. So it should only ask me the n"4" for example and r alwasy should be 2. I know I am asking some complicated thing but I tried for hours but no progress can you help me please.

```
class Program
        {
            static int combin(int a, int b)
            {
                int f1, f2, f3, y;
                f1 = fact(a);
                f2 = fact(b);
                f3 = fact(a - b);
                y = f1 / (f2 * f3);
                return y;
            }
     
            static int fact(int x)
            {
                int fx = 1, i;
                for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
                    fx = fx * i;
                return fx;
            }
     
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                  int n, r, comb;
                Console.WriteLine("n ve r degerlerini giriniz");
                n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                comb = combin(n, r);
                Console.WriteLine("Sonuç:{0}",comb);
                Console.ReadLine();
     
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, don't try and explain everything in the title. Read [ask]; the title should be a brief summary of the longer content in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't ask for 'r' and set a variable to '2':

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n, comb; // don't ask for 'r'
            Console.WriteLine("n ve r degerlerini giriniz");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // don't ask for 'r'
            int r = 2;
            comb = combin(n, r);
            Console.WriteLine("Sonuç:{0}",comb);
            Console.ReadLine();
 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code if someone needs it in future and thank you again Jonathan.

```
static int combin(int a, int b)
        {
            int f1, f2, f3, y;
            f1 = fact(a);
            f2 = fact(b);
            f3 = fact(a - b);
            y = f1 / (f2 * f3);
            return y;
        }

        static int fact(int x)
        {
            int fx = 1, i;
            for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
                fx = fx * i;
            return fx;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n, comb;
            Console.WriteLine("n ve r degerlerini giriniz: ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int r = 2;
            comb = combin(n, r);
            Console.WriteLine("Sonuç:{0}", comb);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```